# Excel 2010 - Compare 2 columns, find matching values

Tags: excel

I am looking help in Excel. I have one excel sheet which have two columns as mentioned below:

```
List 1  List 2
ACBS    ACBS
AXIS    ACBS 12
        ACBS 56
        AXIS
        AXIS Bank
        AXIS National Bank
        Test
        Test 1
        Dummy Test
```

List 2 is the master list in which I have to search matching record available in List 1 and desired result should be as mentioned below:

```
Mapping List
ACBS    ACBS
        ACBS 12
        ACBS 56
AXIS    AXIS
        AXIS Bank
        AXIS National Bank
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear from your question what data do you have and what you are trying to achieve. I guess VLOOKUP is a universal solution. If you have several columns to match, just concatenate them

Answer (score 0):

As well as vlookup there is also an excellent addon available from http://www.ablebits.com/ that has that feature within it.  I've been using it for free for ages but it may be on a free trial basis now which may be enough for your requirements!?